# libgdx: game crushes on all tablets, but works on phones

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My game allready in play market : Paper Plane - Tap Game (if u need it to test and take logs).

On tablets i've got error: Unfortunately Paper Plane has stopped. But on phones game works fine.

In Play Console Android Vitals:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:5155)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:4714)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4647)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:162)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1424)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5426)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:842)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:609)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:501)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:461)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:5140)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Looks like the bottom of your stack trace is missing above. That's the part with the necessary debugging info.

Comment: Looks like it fails in creating some activity. From the fact that it works on phones but not tablets, are you trying to access some activity like the phone or address book? What does your AndroidManifest.xml look like?

Comment: @DHa nope. All i added to manifest is in

`<activity
            android:name="com.mamaraisedmeright.paperplane.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

**android:screenOrientation="portrait"**

Comment: How do you know it is only appearing on tablets? Could it instead be related to the version of Android?